# Airflow Scheduler HA

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Can anyone guide me if am doing anything wrong :
Objective : Want to set up scheduler HA .
Versions :  Backend db - Postgres 12.6 , Airflow 2.1.1
Challenges: When scheduler is started on first machine , it works as expected and i was able to trigger the example _bash_operator but when scheduler is started on  another host with the same backend connection .
My first scheduler fails and it gives me the below error when am trying to click on the bash_oprator_example dag in WebUI

ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5` generally occurs when you have a different version of Python running on both machines.

Verify that you have same versions of Python on both machines

Comment: How do i make sure its using different version of python ? I see its using python3.6 only in the error log

Comment: Run `python -V` on both the machines - that should give you the default Python version that is installed. I am assuming here that you have not used a Virtual Evnironment